# PowerShell module variables

Tags: powershell, variables, module, manifest

How do I use a variable in a module called from another script?

I've looked a long while for examples before asking this simple question. Every example I've found, including Microsoft's documentation only shows how to make a module and manifest and never an implementation. Because of this, I am unable to determine if I am just calling the variable wrong OR if I am unable to make an object reference in a module.

My functions are being called so the imports/exports are working as expected, and I am using a manifest to do so.

```
#
# Format-BLAH.psm1
#

$MyVar = New-Object MyClass($param)

# Functions declared below.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually export variables:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Variable MyVar
```

Comment: My manifest doesn't do this for me?

Comment: @user3812871 no, in fact there's a better answer on the site already that explains the combination of the Manifest and `Export-ModuleMember`; will vote to close as dup.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the purpose of 


"FunctionsToExport = '*'"

In the manifest?

Comment: @user3812871 It can actually be used to further limit what is exported by `Export-ModuleMember`